# Strange filename encoding

Tags: bash, filesystems

I have a strange issue regarding a filename.
Summary of the situation is:

```
[username@xxx tmp]$ ll
-rw-r--r--. 1 xxx xxx 42694  8. Jun 19:56 12287_KKL_Messegerät_EF_30.1.pdf
-rw-r--r--. 1 xxx xxx 42694  8. Jun 19:56 12287_KKL_Messegerät_EF_30.1.pdf
```

In fact, filename and content of the two files are identical. The source where is the file is from contains some similar files. To reproduce, here an example:

```
$ mount
/dev/vda1 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,nodiratime,grpquota)
$ touch ä
$ ll ä
-rw-r--r--. 1 xxx xxx 0  8. Jun 19:59 ä
```

So in general, Umlauts work. Now I delete the files in the directory and copy the weird file to the empty directory:

```
[username@xxx tmp]$ rm *
[username@xxx tmp]$ cp /tmp/12287_KKL_Messegerät_EF_30.1.pdf .
[username@xxx tmp]$ ll 12287*
-rw-r--r--. 1 xxx xxx 42694  8. Jun 20:01 12287_KKL_Messegerät_EF_30.1.pdf
[username@xxx tmp]$ ll 12287_KKL_Messegerät_EF_30.1.pdf
ls: Zugriff auf 12287_KKL_Messegerät_EF_30.1.pdf nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

That means, accessing the file directly does not work. If I rename it forth and back however, it works:

```
[username@xxx tmp]$ mv 12287_KKL_Messegerät_EF_30.1.pdf 12287_KKL_Messegerät_EF_30.1.pdf_
[username@xxx tmp]$ mv 12287_KKL_Messegerät_EF_30.1.pdf_ 12287_KKL_Messegerät_EF_30.1.pdf
[username@xxx tmp]$ ll 12287_KKL_Messegerät_EF_30.1.pdf
-rw-r--r--. 1 xxx xxx 42694  8. Jun 20:01 12287_KKL_Messegerät_EF_30.1.pdf
[username@xxx tmp]$
```

Any idea what's going on?

-- UPDATE --

Output of /proc/mounts:

```
$ cat /proc/mounts
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime,hidepid=2 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
devtmpfs /dev devtmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,size=12292684k,nr_inodes=3073171,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,seclabel,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,size=12302624k,nr_inodes=3075656 0 0
/dev/vda1 / ext4 rw,seclabel,noatime,nodiratime,barrier=1,stripe=128,data=ordered,grpquota 0 0
none /selinux selinuxfs rw,relatime 0 0
devtmpfs /dev devtmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,size=12292684k,nr_inodes=3073171,mode=755 0 0
/proc/bus/usb /proc/bus/usb usbfs rw,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /var/lib/php-sessions tmpfs rw,rootcontext=system_u:object_r:var_lib_t:s0,seclabel,relatime,size=9784216k,nr_inodes=2446054,mode=1333 0 0
none /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,relatime 0 0
/etc/auto.misc /misc autofs rw,relatime,fd=7,pgrp=6943,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,indirect 0 0
-hosts /net autofs rw,relatime,fd=13,pgrp=6943,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,indirect 0 0
sunrpc /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs rpc_pipefs rw,relatime 0 0
```

-- UPDATE --

Indeed the files have different inodes:

```
26346402 -rw-r--r--. 1 xxx xxx  42694  8. Jun 19:49 12287_KKL_Messegerät_EF_30.1.pdf
26360081 -rw-r--r--. 1 xxx xxx  42694 30. Mai 2012  12287_KKL_Messegerät_EF_30.1.pdf
```

Comment: Provide the poutput of /proc/self/mounts. I also assume you are doing this in /tmp?

Comment: Updated the description. No, the working directory is something like /home/username/tmp

Comment: `$ ll 12287_KKL_Messegerät_EF_30.1.pdf` are you tab-completing that filename, or typing/copying and pasting? There are 2 byte sequences to represent `ä`, ¨ + a (U+00A8 + U+0061) or ä (U+00E4).

Comment: on typing "ll 12287_KKL_Messeger<tab>", it autocompletes correctly. On pasting "ll 12287_KKL_Messeger", it answers "file not found"

Comment: When there's any doubt as to the filename or the possibility of two filenames linked to one file, work with the inode numbers and use cat to expand any unprintable characters.  `ls -li` and `ls -l | cat -vet` should uncover what's going on.

Comment: Yes, the files have different inodes. So do you have any idea how to "repair" the file which does not respond to tab completion? Renaming all files forth and back seems not to be an ideal solution.

Comment: Combining @AD7six and @Smiling Dragon's suggestions with a locale setting (just in case), try `ls 12287* | LC_ALL=C cat -vet`. I'm betting one file is listed as "12287_KKL_MessegerM-CM-$t_EF_30.1.pdf$" and the other as "12287_KKL_MessegeraM-LM-^Ht_EF_30.1.pdf$". The difference  is "M-CM-$" (hex c3a4, which is UTF-8 for U+00E4, "a" with umlaut) vs "aM-LM-^H" ("a" + hex cc88, UTF-8 for U+0061, combining umlaut). They *look* identical, but they're different byte strings, and hence different filenames. Look up [equivalence in unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) and weep.

Comment: @GordonDavisson exact, you're right. Now looking for a way to rename them all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from all comments, I wrote a python script to normalize all files recursively:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8
import unicodedata
import sys,os

# Walks recursively through directory and normalizes all filenames to NFC

for dirPath, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    for fname in fileList:
        d = os.path.join(dirPath, fname)
        filename = unicodedata.normalize('NFC', unicode(d, 'utf-8')).encode('utf-8')
        print d, "=>", filename
        os.rename(d, filename)
```

Thanks everyone!